# Exporting customer addresses messes up CSV

Tags: magento-1.9, csv, export, customer-csv

I have been trying to export customer addresses from magento, but I have a issue with the 2nd line off the street address.  No matter what way i export it ( magentos dataflow or directly from the database) when the CSV is created it seems the 2nd line of the address is creates a new line.  So when I export instead of having a line for each record, I some times have 2 lines (if there is a 2nd line in the address) which messes up the formatting:

So what i get is:

```
Customer name, "Address line 1
address line 2", more customer details
```

instead off:

```
Customer name, "Address line 1 address line 2", more customer details
```

There must be a "next line" for the 2nd line of the address, how can I get around this, so I can have the correct formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exported as a HTML file instead of a CSV ( I'm using mysql benchmark) and I have been able to copy that into excel in a workable format.